# Unexpected output when creating a list of frequent words. How can I get the top 10 most frequent words for a given class?

Tags: python, counter, data-analysis, word-frequency, exploratory-data-analysis

I am trying to get the top 10 most frequent words per class in my dataset. I have the following Python code but I do not understand the output, why this has occurred and how it can be corrected.

Below is the dataset I am using (df)

```
User    Post    Label
0   Nicholas Wyman  Exploring in this months Talent Management HR...    Recruitment
1   Nicholas Wyman  I count myself fortunate to have spent time wi...   Career
2   Nicholas Wyman  This years National Apprenticeship Week comes ...   Recruitment
3   Nicholas Wyman  How will your company tap into workers as a co...   Wellbeing
4   Nicholas Wyman  The momentum for Modern Apprenticeships is bui...   Recruitment
```

This is the code I am using

```
#Import dataset
df = pd.read_csv("Folds1345.csv", engine='python',encoding='latin-1')

#Get classes
classes = df['Label'].unique()
classes = classes.tolist()

#Check each class and produce top 10 words
for i in classes:
  print(i)
  df2=df.loc[df['Label'] == i, 'Post']
  df2 = str(remove_stopwords(df['Post']))
  from collections import Counter
  Frequent = Counter(" ".join(df2).split()).most_common(10)
  print(Frequent)
```

And this is the output

```
Recruitment
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
Career
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
Wellbeing
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
Rewards
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
Technology
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
Learning
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
HR System
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
Inclusion
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
Diversity
[("'", 1213698), (',', 606859), ('e', 507474), ('i', 321003), ('a', 311593), ('n', 303956), ('t', 296568), ('s', 290978), ('r', 276802), ('o', 261175)]
```

It seems to be looking at individual letters rather than words and searching the entire dataset rather than just the posts with the chosen label, but I cannot work out why.

Comment: Please do not keep changing the question when you solved the initial question. This is not how Stack Overflow works. If the initial question has been solved, you could accept the answer and ask a new question (do not forgot to search for existing solutions first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Import dataset
df = pd.read_csv("Folds1345.csv", engine='python',encoding='latin-1')

#Get classes
classes = df['Label'].unique()
classes = classes.tolist()

for i in classes:
  print(i)
  df2=df.loc[df['Label'] == i, 'Post']
  df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x))
  list_sentences = df2.to_list()
  from collections import Counter
  list_words = (' '.join(str(s) for s in list_sentences)).split(' ')
  Frequent = Counter(list_words).most_common(10)
  print(Frequent)
```

EDIT: You df2 is first a pandas series and then a string. I am not sure what "remove_stopwords" function you are using, I guess it is the one from gensim. I adapted the code

EDIT2: this time it should work

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code gave me an entire sentence as output but since I am looking for the words rather than posts I have tried to adapt it as shown in my post above, however, I get an error message.

Comment: I tried it but I got an error as sentences was defined as a variable before, so I tried with list_words as I guess this is what you meant, however, I get an error message. I have including this in the post now.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer. I also modified the lane for the "stop_word function". However, you are not copying the code correctly. First, you obtain a list of sentences using " list_sentences = df2.to_list()". Then, you join this list into one string " ' '.join(list_sentences) " and finally obtain a list of words " list_words = (' '.join(list_sentences)).split(' ') ". Please try a direct copy of the code in the answer.

Comment: I have copied again with a direct copy but it is still producing an error and I can't work out why :S

Comment: The line "   df = df2.apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x)) "  should be "  df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x)) ". As in the answer. I edited it. We were overwriting df

Comment: I have tried but I am now getting the following error : `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

Comment: I edited (again) the code. It seems like there is a problem with your "Post" column. Maybe you have a list inside it